Docusign - Notification for Admin Email Upon Document Signing/Rejection
I am setting up a Docusign workflow where:
The Signer role can sign or reject documents.
The Admin role should receive an email notification when the signer either signs or rejects a document.
The admin should not have the ability to sign the document themselves.
Currently, both roles seem to have the ability to sign the document, which is not the intended behavior. How can I configure DocuSign so that:
Only the Signer role can sign or reject documents.
The Admin role receives an email notification when the signer completes their action.
Please advise on the correct setup or configuration steps needed to achieve this. Thank you for your assistance.
Here is my java Code:



Currently, both roles seem to have the ability to sign the document

Not sure why you think this, but your code looks correct, a CC recipient cannot sign, only get an email.
Now, note that you did not set routing order, that is, you can decide that the CC only gets the envelope after the first signer signs.
Regardless of any of this, the changes has to be made to the template directly, not the code. The code here is simply filling the information about the recipients, but the template was set a certain way - and that's how it will later work.
Make sure you template has 2 recipients, one is called "signer" and one is called "cc" and make sure the "cc" recipient has a higher routing order (assuming that's what you want).
Then, the same code will work just fine.
